# Questions regarding developing a kiosk chrome application

Tags: touch, kiosk, kiosk-mode, chromebook

I am asked to build a kiosk application that will be run on chrome books in a school. The basic requirement is to have two interfaces one for principal and others for classrooms. The principal will have rooms listed on its interface and he can send certain messages to the room(s). And room can send an acknowledgment of reading by tapping on a message. I am totally noob regarding this. I have a couple of questions:

1. I can develop a web application using HTML/CSS/PHP that I can host on a server and then I can link the domain to kiosk setup? Is my understanding correct?
2. I can use any socket programming protocol to send those messages to the room(s) and receive back acknowledgment or kiosk has its some that I am still unable to find?

Sorry for if these are too basic. I am writing because I haven't found solutions from google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network capability in a browser is limited. Websocket is a specific protocol. You'll need to sync messages between principal and students using push-pull with regular requests using fetch() or xhrhttprequest. Or you can use Websockets. I'd recommend looking into socket.io. It has supports for rooms and handles downgrading to regular requests if Websockets are not working.

https://socket.io/

For the kiosk part, you can add progressive webapps to chromeos kiosk on managed chromebooks.
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9781496?hl=en

I have not seen anyway you can detect it is actually running in kiosk at the moment.